# Arduino Due connection with FLIR Lepton

Tags: arduino-due

I'm trying to connect a FLIR Lepton to an Arduino Due. A [thread by pureengineering](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=266361.0) talks of rerouting some pins. I am not sure what they precisely mean.

[image]

Does this rerouting mentioned in the link also apply to Arduino Due?

Answer (score 1):

According to the highlighted part of `Due` schematics it'd be better to connect `3.3V` to the `AREF` pin as there might be some significantly big resistor between `AREF` and `3.3V` source. So it might not be needed but one never knows.

Edit: Looking at the DUE board, there is "jumper" resistor, so you can choose 3V3 or AREF, that means AREF is not connected to anything by default. So if you connect 3v3 to AREF, it should be fine (even 5V, if you didn't changed anything on board yet
)

[image]